# Making a Custom Drawing Method available throughout entire application

Tags: c#, winforms

I've added a custom border to the labels in one of my application forms as follows:

```
    private void ColorMe(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(104, 195, 198);
        Pen myPen = new Pen(myColor, 1);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen,
        e.ClipRectangle.Left,
        e.ClipRectangle.Top,
        e.ClipRectangle.Width - 1,
        e.ClipRectangle.Height - 1);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    private void lblDisbs_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        ColorMe(e);
    }
```

Which works nicely.  All I have to do it put ColorMe(e) in the Paint Event of each label.

However I want to use this method on all forms throughout the whole application.  I tried putting my ColorMe() method in a class to call it from multiple forms that way, but it does not work, saying that 'base has no OnPaint event'.

How should I make this method available throughout the whole application?

Comment: Remember to dispose of your Pen object...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create class `LabelWithBorder` derive it from `Label`, override the `OnPaint` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx).

```
public class LabelWithBorder : Label {
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    ColorMe(e);
  }
}
```

Replace all WinForms labels in your app with your label.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "Repalce all WinForms labels in your app with your label".  How is this done?  There are hundreds of labels. Can I not just add a drawing method to each existing label.

Comment: Find all references of Label control and replace them. What's the difference between replacing every label and adding one method to each existing label (whatever it means)?

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't use the `ClipRectangle` for drawing in this case, since it would produce malformed rectangles on your control.

If not using Karel Frajtak's solution, which is cleaner, you can try making a static class and then you can call it from any form:

```
internal static class LabelBorder {
  public static void ColorMe(Rectangle r, PaintEventArgs e) {
    r.Inflate(-1, -1);

    using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(104, 195, 198), 1))
      e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, r);
  }
}
```

Example:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  label1.Paint += label_Painter;
  label2.Paint += label_Painter;
}

void label_Painter(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  LabelBorder.ColorMe(((Label)sender).ClientRectangle, e);
}
```